# Pending status Paypal Express Checkout

Tags: php, paypal

I have a question relative to status of paypal transaction

Now I am using Express Checkout API. But when I made a payment and then go to activity tab in sandbox paypal. I saw status of transactions was pendding. So how do I make it to status completed?

Thanks in advance./.

Comment: did PaymentAction = A or S? it will pend if it was A. if it's S it should complete.

Comment: Thanks @KevinG You mean PaymentAction is a parameter in ExpressCheckout, right?

Comment: Yes , in the Set call you choose to either Authorize the transaction for later capture, or Sale, to pull the funds from the card immediately. (A or S)

Comment: another case could be that the payment is in a currency A and your paypal acccount has a balance in B. Default behaviour is to set the transaction in pending waiting for a manual accept by the seller or you can set currency conversion as default on your seller account